# Как отправить ajax запрос в конце ввода текста в форму?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `input` с `id = "tagname"`. Сейчас, после ввода каждой буквы, выполняется ajax запрос.

```
$("#tagname").bind('input',function(e){
        $.ajax({ // Тело ajax запроса });
});
```

Как можно сделать задержку отправки в 2сек?
Пробовал так:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({ // Тело ajax запроса });
},2000);
```

Задержка добавляется, но после нее выполняется несколько ajax запросов(зависит от количества введенных символов). А нужно, чтобы выполнялся один запрос в конце ввода.

Тоесть после каждой нажатой кнопки счетчик должен сбрасываться, если в течении этих 2сек был введен еще символ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var timerId;
$("#tagname").bind('input',function(e){
       clearTimeout(timerId);
       timerId = setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({ // Тело ajax запроса });
        },2000);
});
```